# How to find what caused stack overflow in a large javascript file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have a huge JS file on my page (more than 25k lines of code) which does a lot of stuff. I added just one line to it to set a cookie and after doing so I start getting the error in Chrome "Maximum call stack size exceeded" (in FF "too much recursion"). But in either of these tools when I click the line of code in the error console where the error is, it doesn't seem to be the real cause.

Is there anyway to identify where the stack overflow started? Where things started going wrong?

Comment: Yes, reviewing and debugging the code ... without seeing the code it is difficult :)

Comment: Yes, that is the long and hard way but it would be nice if one of these JS tools like firebug or chrome devtools could tell me which is the function that has gone over the call limit (and who maybe who called that function).

Comment: Devtools in IE11 seems to show a line which has broken camel's neck ... And actually FF and Chrome does that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a recursive function that goes over the call limit (JS Engine limits the recursive calls to around 10.000), so your function does not end, and goes in an infinite call.

The problem should be on the function you are calling, you can see the function call stack in google chrome sources (set some breakpoints to where you think it might happen, or where you changed your code).

On the right you will notice the call stack dropdown, there you should have a good idea which function is causing the issue.

*Image for reference.

[image]